# Trigonometry expansion of a product

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

The following command does what I want:

```
TrigExpand[ Cos[a + b]^2]

(* 1/2 + 1/2 Cos[a]^2 Cos[b]^2 - 1/2 Cos[b]^2 Sin[a]^2 - 
   2 Cos[a] Cos[b] Sin[a] Sin[b] - 1/2 Cos[a]^2 Sin[b]^2 + 
   1/2 Sin[a]^2 Sin[b]^2 *)
```

Unfortunately, it does not apply the distributive property of the product in another case, that is the one I am interested in:

```
TrigExpand[ Cos[c*(a + b)]^2]

(*  Cos[c*(a + b)]^2  *)
```

How can I tell *Mathematica* to do that initial step?

Comment: Try `TrigReduce[Cos[c*(a + b)]^2]`, it yields `1/2 (1 + Cos[2 (a + b) c])`

Comment: Sure, but that's not the result I want, which must be in terms of Cos[a*c] and Sin[b*c], like the first one above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some clarification in the comments you expect the result in terms of `Sin[a c]` and  `Cos[a c]`.  For this purpose one can use [`MapAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAll.html) (a shorthand `//@`). It is not so common as `Map` (`/@`) but sometimes it can be very handy:

```
TrigExpand //@ ( Cos[c (a + b)]^2)
```

> ```
> 1/2 + 1/2 Cos[a c]^2 Cos[b c]^2 - 1/2 Cos[b c]^2 Sin[a c]^2 
>  - 2 Cos[a c] Cos[b c] Sin[a c] Sin[b c] - 1/2 Cos[a c]^2 Sin[b c]^2 
>  + 1/2 Sin[a c]^2 Sin[b c]^2
> ```

Comment: you get the endresult if you use MapAll in its non-shorthand form...MapAll[TrigExpand, Cos[c (a + b)]^2]

Comment: Thanks, both of you, Map and MapAll will be useful in many situations. For curiosity, do you know why the non-shorthand form behaves differently?

Comment: @Stefan It hasn't been the reason, just only overlooked braces `()`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @flebool Look at the edit, the shorthand form works correctly.

Comment: @Artes ah. ok :) i've overseen it as well...was already confused about the different results.

Answer (score 2):

Artes' method is pleasingly concise, because it uses `TrigExpand` to expand `c*(a + b)` to `a c + b c` by mapping it to that specific part.  Another approach is to use [`ExpandAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExpandAll.html):

> ExpandAll[*expr*] expands out all products and integer powers in any part of *expr*.

```
Cos[c*(a + b)]^2 // ExpandAll // TrigExpand
```

> ```
> 1/2 + 1/2 Cos[a c]^2 Cos[b c]^2 - 1/2 Cos[b c]^2 Sin[a c]^2 - 
>  2 Cos[a c] Cos[b c] Sin[a c] Sin[b c] - 1/2 Cos[a c]^2 Sin[b c]^2 + 
>  1/2 Sin[a c]^2 Sin[b c]^2
> ```

This may be somewhat faster on large expressions.